# Alerta "Toasts" Materialize com Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize, toasts

Estou com falta de entendimento de como aplicar o [Toasts](https://materializecss.com/toasts.html) do Materialize em um código Rails.

```
    <% if notice %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
    <% end %>
```

No devise, ele me dá esses alertas, porém quero usar o efeito do materialize.